# onchange doesnt work for firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Select onchange works for Chrome and Opera but it doesnt work for Firefox. Would you mind helping me ? What should I do to fix it for all browsers?

```js
var tehlikeliNace = ["01.11.07", "01.11.12"];
var aztehlikeliNace = ["01.30.04", "01.63.05"];
var coktehlikeliNace = ["01.61.04", "01.61.06"];

function naceKoduDegisti() {


  if (jQuery.inArray($("#nace_kod").val(), aztehlikeliNace) >= 0) {
    $("#tehlike_sinifi option[value='1']").attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
  if (jQuery.inArray($("#nace_kod").val(), tehlikeliNace) >= 0) {
    $("#tehlike_sinifi option[value='2']").attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
  if (jQuery.inArray($("#nace_kod").val(), coktehlikeliNace) >= 0) {
    $("#tehlike_sinifi option[value='3']").attr('selected', 'selected');
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="nace_kod" onchange="naceKoduDegisti()">
  <option value="01.11.07">01.11.07</option>
  <option value="01.30.04">01.30.04</option>
  <option value="01.61.04">01.63.05</option>
  <option value="01.11.12">01.13.18</option>
  <option value="01.63.05">02.40.04</option>
</select>

<select id="tehlike_sinifi">
  <option value="1">"Az Tehlikeli"</option>
  <option value="2">"Tehlikeli"</option>
  <option value="3">"Çok Tehlikeli"</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never remove the attribute `selected` on your `option` tag. So after using your script, your html code looks like :

```
<select id="tehlike_sinifi"> 
    <option value="1" selected="selected">"Az Tehlikeli"</option>      
    <option value="2" selected="selected">"Tehlikeli"</option> 
    <option value="3" selected="selected">"Çok Tehlikeli"</option>     
</select>
```

Firefox does not know which option to choose.

Try to use the function `val()` instead of set the attribute `selected`.

[From jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val)

> [jQuery.val] checks, or selects, all the radio buttons, checkboxes, and select options that match the set of values.

With the function `val()`, it's working fine.

```
if ($.inArray($("#nace_kod").val(), aztehlikeliNace) >= 0) {
    $("#tehlike_sinifi").val(1);
}
if ($.inArray($("#nace_kod").val(), tehlikeliNace) >= 0) {
    $("#tehlike_sinifi").val(2);
}
if ($.inArray($("#nace_kod").val(), coktehlikeliNace) >= 0) {
    $("#tehlike_sinifi").val(3);
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wzfcwm8k/1/)

Comment: I use this script on Firfox and it's working. Did you have any error message?

Comment: I dont get any error message.. It works for 2 or 3 changing but more it doesnt work.

Comment: @Burak My bad, I updated my answer with the correct way

Comment: Ok mate it is solved now.. Thanks for your interest :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep your function script in `head` else it will give error  `ReferenceError: naceKoduDegisti is not defined`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/L8vo7dk2/2/)**

```
<head>
 ....
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tehlikeliNace = ["01.11.07", "01.11.12"];
    var aztehlikeliNace = ["01.30.04", "01.63.05"];
    var coktehlikeliNace = ["01.61.04", "01.61.06"];
    function naceKoduDegisti() {
       if (jQuery.inArray($("#nace_kod").val(), aztehlikeliNace) >= 0) {
          $("#tehlike_sinifi option[value='1']").attr('selected', 'selected');
       }
       if (jQuery.inArray($("#nace_kod").val(), tehlikeliNace) >= 0) {
          $("#tehlike_sinifi option[value='2']").attr('selected', 'selected');
       }
       if (jQuery.inArray($("#nace_kod").val(), coktehlikeliNace) >= 0) {
          $("#tehlike_sinifi option[value='3']").attr('selected', 'selected');
       }
    }
</script>
</head>
```